# Is this how JSON is supposed to be, or can it be more optimal in terms of space?

Tags: javascript, php, json, wordpress

In my code I have

```
var team = <?php echo json_encode(get_results("SELECT id,name,title,bio,sord,picfn FROM mems ORDER BY sord")); ?>;
```

which generates a JavaScript array of object like

```
var team = [{"id":"1","name":"somename1","title":"sometitle1","somebio1":"...","sord":"69","picfn":"somepicfn1"},{"id":"2","name":"somename2","title":"sometitle2","bio":"sometitle2","sord":"3","picfn":"somepicfn2"},...];
```

To me, that seems very inefficient to repeat the field names `"id"`, `"name"`, `"title"`, `"bio`", `"sord"`, `"picfn"` in every object of the array. Wouldn't it be more efficient to have the objects in the array simply be the value of the fields, e.g.

`{"1, "somename", "sometitle1", "someboi1", "1", "somepicfn1"}`

and have a separate structure that maps keys to indices, e.g.

```
var map = {"id" : 0, "name" : 1, "title" : 2, "bio" : 3, "sord" : 4, "picfn" : 5};
```

???

Or is there something important that I'm missing here?

Comment: The ordering is irrelevant for JSON, which is why the keys are explicitly listed.

Comment: You could restructure the results before using `json_encode` but in short yes that's how it should be with what you've provided it.

Comment: That's what JSON is like. There are minifiers that do things like you suggest, but their practicality is questionable given that a server concerned with minimizing bandwidth will probably be using gzip to compress everything anyway; the savings from optimizing the JSON are generally not very impressive.

Comment: Of course you're free to come up with your own data structure to reduce redundancy for things like big tables of homogeneous rows.

Comment: If you want to use arrays and have it be in a specific order to be a key, that is valid, but it is not easy to read. Guessing you have not worked with XML.

Answer (score 0):

The Json is a string, so you can't really optimize it.
you have to provide every key/value each time you got an element inside it.

Oh and by the way, don't put a result of a query directly in your js, please separate your code a bit, use variables...

Comment: by 'is a string' i mean can be interpreted as a string, it has it specific bracket + key/value format anyway, but the content is stored in a string

Answer (score 0):

You can separate column names and values like this for example:

```
json_encode( [
    'columns'   => array_keys( $team[0] ),
    'values'    => array_map( function( $v ) { 
        return array_values( $v ); 
    }, get_results( "SELECT id,name,title,bio,sord,picfn FROM mems ORDER BY sord" ) )
] );

/* output:
{"columns":["id","name","title","bio","sord","picfn"],"values":[["1","somename1","sometitle1","sometitle1","69","somepicfn1"],["2","somename2","sometitle2","sometitle2","3","somepicfn2"],["3","somename3","sometitle3","sometitle3","4","somepicfn3"]]}
*/
```